# Python dictionary to dictionary mapping

Tags: python, recursion

I'm looking for recursion dynamic function/library to mapping dictionary with specific keys.

Example

```
my_data = {
    'name': 'Test',
    'primary_address': {
        'full_address': 'Address test',
    },
    'other_field': 'Other field'
}

mapping_keys = {
  'name': 'full_name',
  'primary_address__full_address': 'primary_address__address'
}
```

Expected result

```
{
    'full_name': 'Test',
    'primary_address': {
        'address': 'Address test',
     }
}
```

What I tried, but it doesn't work with recursion

```
def mapping_data(json_data, mapping_keys):
    mapped_data = []
    for data in json_data:
        mapped_data_tmp = {}
        for key in data:
            if key in mapping_keys:
                mapped_data_tmp.update({mapping_keys[key]: data[key]})
        mapped_data.append(mapped_data_tmp)
    return mapped_data
```

Comment: What you have tried?

Comment: TBH I doubt that there is library function for your use case, as it seems quite specific, on the other hand it should be quite easy to write your own function to do what you need

Comment: @YogeshMhaskule I updated question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from functools import reduce
import operator

my_data = {
    'name': 'Test',
    'primary_address': {
        'full_address': 'Address test',
    },
    'other_field': 'Other field'
}

mapping_keys = {
  'name': 'full_name',
  'primary_address__full_address': 'primary_address__address'
}

def get_item_by_path(data,path):
    return reduce(operator.getitem,path,data)

def set_item_by_path(data, path, value): 
    try: 
        get_item_by_path(data, path[:-1])[path[-1]] = value 
    except KeyError: 
        for key in reversed(path): 
            value = {key: value} 
        data[path[0]] = value[path[0]] 

def mapKeys(data, mapping_keys):
    result = {}
    for oldkey in mapping_keys:
        oldkeys = oldkey.split('__')
        val = get_item_by_path(my_data, oldkeys)
        newkeys = mapping_keys[oldkey].split('__')
        set_item_by_path(result, newkeys, val)
    return result

newDict = mapKeys(my_data, mapping_keys)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
def mapping_data(json_data, mapping_keys, prefix=''):
    mapped_data = {}
    for key, val in json_data.items():
        map_key = (prefix + '__' + key) if prefix else key

        if map_key in mapping_keys:   
            key = mapping_keys[map_key].rsplit('__', 1)[-1] 
            mapped_data[key] = val    

        if isinstance(val, dict):
            val = mapping_data(val, mapping_keys, map_key)
            mapped_data[key] = val

    return mapped_data

res = mapping_data(my_data, mapping_keys)
print (res)
```

**Output**

```
{
    "full_name": "Test",
    "primary_address": {
        "address": "Address test"
    }
}
```